# Apache2, vhosts and SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, apache2, vhosts

My setup:
site1.com | Port 80
site2.com | Port 80
panel.site1.com | Rewrites port 80 traffic to 443

This works until someone tries https:// site[x].com and the server redirects them to my panel. I need this panel to be open to the ~100 people who will use it, but I don't want the wrong people stumbling across it.

I've tried adding:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin me@email
    ServerName site1.com
    ServerAlias www.site1.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

to the vhost of site1.com, but it still returns the control panel. I believe this is because the certs are checked before Apache vhost rules are applied, but I'm not really sure. Is there a fix for this or is it simply the limitations of Apache2+SSL?

Answer (score 2):

[Apache document states that](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html).

> If no matching ServerName or ServerAlias is found in the set of
>   virtual hosts containing the most specific matching IP address and
>   port combination, then the first listed virtual host that matches that
>   will be used.

And so looks like you have kept the `<VirtualHost>` section of `panel.site1.com` on top of all other virtual host section. Because of this, requests for `https://site[x].com` will land in it, and so the issue is not related to `SSL`.

**Update:**

You can try below configuration and it should work.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.site1.com
    ServerAlias site1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site1

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^panel.site1.com
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.site2.com
    ServerAlias site2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName panel.site1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/panel
    SSLEngine on
    SSLOptions +StrictRequire
    SSLCertificateFile /opt/apache1/conf/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/apache1/conf/server.key
</VirtualHost>
```

**How this works**

1. When request are for `http://site1.com` the **first** `VirtualHost`
   section will be selected.
2. When request are for `http://site2.com` the **second** `VirtualHost` section will be selected.
3. If a request arrives for `http://site[x].com` then **first** `VirtualHost` section will be selected.
4. If a request arrives for `http://panel.site1.com` the request will be redirected to `https://panel.site1.com` and the **third** `VirtualHost` section will be selected.

Comment: I thought this was my problem until I asked the other sites to listen on port 443. I've updated the question to show my failed attempt.